# Do we need labels in the test set while carrying out supervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a data set on which I want to carryout supervised learning. The training set has labels, but the testing set does not.

Comment: My answer would be **Yes**. I don't know exactly what you are trying to learn (classification, regression, ...), but the test dataset is used to compare the results your network gives with the groundtruth. So if you want to compare it, you need labels. It might be interesting to know why your testing set doesn't have labels.

Comment: The question is a bit vague, doesn't make much sense. A bit more info on the issue would be very helpful.

Comment: Generally you use the test set for measuring performance on data not used in training. So if you want to know how well your model performs on data that your model didnt see in training then yes you need labels for the test data.

Answer (score 3):

The important concept here is **evaluation**:

- Either one wants to apply the model for the purpose of evaluating it. In this case, the test data must be labelled because in supervised learning one evaluates a model by comparing its predictions against the true answers.
- Or one just wants to apply the model in order to obtain its predictions for some data.

There might be confusion about the term "test set":

- One can always apply a supervised model to some new instances, and it's quite common to call any data on which the data is applied "test data" by contrast to the training data (technically it should probably be called "production data" actually). Ultimately a supervised model is intended to predict the target variable on some unlabelled data (that's the whole point) so of course one can apply the model to some unlabelled "test" data.
- But from the point of view of building an ML model, only evaluation matters: applying the model to some unlabelled data is not really relevant since it doesn't provide any information about how well the model works. This is why in virtually every ML book/course about supervised learning the test set is understood as a labelled test set, i.e. which can be used for evaluation.

If you have a labelled training set but no labelled test set, it means that you will have to split your training set in order to evaluate the model. Otherwise, when you apply the model to the test set you would have no idea whether the predictions are correct or not, so the model would be useless.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is yes. Example, I hope you are aware of [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function provided by scikit learn which returns pairs train and test data with features and labels. To evaluvate the the accuracy of model, we can use function as follows,

```
def r2_score(Y_actual,Y_predicted):
    num = np.sum((Y_actual-Y_predicted)**2)
    denom = np.sum((Y_actual- Y_actual.mean())**2)
    score = (1- num/denom)
    return score*100
```

As the function will give you more idea ([r2 score](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-r-squared-in-regression-analysis/)) that without labelling how we can predict the model is good enough (in supervised learning) if the accuracy is very less. i.e.

1. The accuracy of train data may very high and very less on test data which indicates that our model may be overfitting.
2. This helps us to know may be to remove some irrevant features or redudant features or fine tune parameters.
3. This helps to know may be we have to do normaliztion/standardization on data (e.g [z score](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/z-score))
4. [Click to know more details](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147786/what-if-high-validation-accuracy-but-low-test-accuracy-in-research)